# Weak separability.

Tags: functional-analysis

How I can show the following statement?

Let $E$ be a normed space and $A\subseteq E$. Then $A$ is separable if and only if $A$ is weak-separable.

If $A$ is separable, is clear that $A$ is weak-separable. But i have problems with the other implication.

Thanks you!

Comment: Use the Hahn-Banach theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A$ is not separable.  Let $C \subset A$ be countable and let $E$ be the $\mathbb{Q}$-linear span of $C$ (i.e. $E = \{ q_1 x_1 + \dots + q_n x_n : q_i \in \mathbb{Q}, x_i \in C, n \in \mathbb{N}\}$) which is also countable.  The closure $\bar{E}$ is a closed linear subspace of $A$, but since $E$ is countable and $A$ is not separable, $\bar{E} \ne A$.  So by the Hahn-Banach theorem, there is a nonzero continuous linear functional $f \in A^*$ such that $f(\bar{E}) = 0$.  Then the kernel of $f$ is a proper weakly closed subset of $A$ which contains $\bar{E}$ and in particular $C$, so $C$ is not weakly dense in $A$.   $C$ was an arbitrary countable set so $A$ is not weakly separable.